# Rewriting plane as a vector equation

Tags: vectors

If a plane is given by the vectors $a,x,y$  such as $r=a + m x + n y$ , how can it be rewritten as the vector equation $(r-a).n = 0$?

I understand that $n$ is normal to the plane, but how do I prove this?

Comment: I haven't seen the form r=a+mx+ny for a plane before, are you sure about that? Are you interested in the case of being given three position vectors of points in the plane, or three vectors that lie in the plane?

Comment: Your question would be improved by using \mathbf{r} etc. to indicate a vector. This would clearly distinguish them from scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{y}$.

Use the fact that $\mathbf{p} \cdot (\mathbf p \times \mathbf q)=\mathbf{q} \cdot (\mathbf p \times \mathbf q)=0$.

$(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{a})\cdot\mathbf{n}=m\mathbf{x}\cdot(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf y)+n\mathbf{y}\cdot(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf y)=0$.